# For use of constructor in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a class that has 2 properties and a constructor:

```
public class Card
{
    public int CardName {get;set;}
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}

    public Card (int cardName, bool isActive)
    {
        CardName = cardName;
        IsActive = isActive;
    }
}
```

How do I force the developer to use the constructor instead of doing the following:

```
var card = new Card{ CardName = "blab", IsActive = true };
```

On a side note, what is the statement above called? Is that a lazy loading statement?

Comment: its called an "object initializer": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: also, "blab" is not a valid int :)

Comment: The reason you are able to create a new Card that way is because you are probably providing a default constructor that takes 0 parameters.

    public Card(){ /*Empty*/ }

Comment: @Michael, thanks!. I wrote that class as an example, I am surprised that was the only mistake I made! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have.

By not having an empty constructor you've removed the ability to use the object initializer method of creating an object.

This:

```
var card = new Card{ CardName = "blab", IsActive = true };
```

is the same as this

```
var card = new Card() { CardName = "blab", IsActive = true };
```

And in this context `new Card()` is not valid.

Comment: Hmmm yea don't know why I didn't think of just trying that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That depends on why you want to prevent the syntax in question.

The object initializer syntax is shorthand for setting a bunch of properties immediately after construction. That is, this:

```
var c = new Card { CardName = "foo", IsActive = true };
```

Is semantically identical to this:

```
var c = new Card();
c.CardName = "foo";
c.IsActive = true;
```

In both cases, a constructor *does* run, but its immediately followed by a series of property initializers to apply to the new object.

In your case, since there is no parameterless constructor, you cannot use the object initializer syntax the way you posted. However, it *is* legal to pass constructor parameters along with the object initializer, so the following *would* be legal for your class:

```
var c = new Card("", false) { CardName = "foo", IsActive = true };
```

(One could argue that this syntax makes the meaning of values more clear than simply passing them to a constructor; one could also argue its just being excessively stubborn :) I could go either way)

You could prevent this second syntax from working by removing the public setters for those properties. If your goal is to prevent the user from changing the values passed into the constructor, making an immutable `Card` object, for example, that would be the way to go.

I should point out, though, that if one of my juniors asked me this question at work I'd really want to know why they found it necessary to prevent object initialization from being used. There are valid reasons, of course, but they are usually not the source of the question.  Object initializers are a good thing -- there are cases where this syntax is very convenient (particularly with LINQ) and I use it all the time.

If you do some kind of setup in the constructor based on the initial values, but those properties are public-settable, you already have to deal with a case where the user changes those values after construction. If your goal is merely to ensure that some "setup" code happens when the object is first constructed, put that code into a default constructor and chain them together:

```
public class Card
{
  public string CardName { get; set; }
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }

  public Card() 
  { 
    // setup code here. 
  }

  public Card ( string name, bool active ) 
    : this()
  {
    this.CardName = name;
    this.IsActive = active;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the getters of the property as 'Private'. 
Something like `Public int CardName {private get; set;}`.